# Activity and Service communication

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

My application consists of one activity which creates a service. I want the service to be keep running as long as application is running. I know:

1. It is not guaranteed as Android system can kill activity in low memory conditions and if activity is in background.
2. The service can be stopped (and killed) by system.
3. If I bind service to the activity, the activity would get notification in case service is being stopped or started. However, the service may stop running if activity goes in background (onStop()). Please correct me if I am wrong here.
4. If I bind to service in onResume() of activity and unbind() in onStop(), it might happen that service stops running when my application goes in background. If I bind in onCreate() and unbind() in onDestroy() of activity, would it mean that my activity will keep getting notification from service even when in background.
5. What is the best way to keep service running and get notification from service to Activity as long as application is running. Please note that there is just one activity in the application so sending activity in background means application goes in background.

Thanks

Comment: You should tag your post with `android-activity` instead of `activity`, and `android-service` instead of `service` :)

Comment: Apologies Alex, will keep in mind in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. true
2. true, but its more rare if us use startForeground()
3. The service usually won't stop until all activities have unbound. But when the last has, it will. So u can prevent the service from dieing when going to background, if you only unbind in onPause if isFinishing() == true.
4. see 3.
5. I personally like to set up a Handler in the Activity and send Messages to it from the service.

Comment: Thanks Martze for reply. If user clicks on return, my activity goes to background instead of exiting application. I have put an exit icon on the app if someone wants to exit app. So, if I put Finnishing= true when user selects exit and unbind() only when user exiting, it should work, I mean service should keep running as long as my application is running (even if it is in background). Am I corrrect?

Comment: When the button is clicked, you should call finish();. Usually, if the user presses the back button the activity should close with isFinishing() == true (and not save its state). and i made a fault up there, you unbind in onPause ofc.

Comment: Thanks..the problem is, if I unbind in onPause, the service might not run when activity is in background. I think i should use Messenger to communicate between Activity and Service and forget bind/unbind.

Comment: if you check in your OnPause() whether the acticity is going in background ( if(isFinishing() == true) -> not background, else -> background), you can tell your app not to loose the service connection in background and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding a `Service` to your `Activity`. It simply means that you need service to run as long as your activity is running. If you do not need to bind `Service` with activity or you do not need to update your `UI` while your `Service` is running. you must not bind your `Service` to your `Activity`. In this case, for different actions done by `Service` you can notify user using `Android Notifications`. Like notifying user that xx download has been completed.

It totally depends upon your purpose that you want to achieve from `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use `IntentService` for your application, you can pass data to the service through an `Intent`. results can be passed back to the Activity through a `ResultReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your `Service` to your unique `Activity`, you'll have it alive as long as the `Activity` is not terminated or the `service` isn't unbound. Just bind it on the `onCreate()` and let it get unbound when stopping your `activity` (no need to do anything).

You can create a Listener `interface` within your `service`, that you'll implement in the `Activity`, so you can send those notifications from the `Service` to the `Activity`. You'll find suitable example and information about this if Googling.

Comment: If i bind it at onCreate() but donot unbind it anywhere, wouldn't it be a problem when my activity goes background? when you say, let it get unbound when stopping your activity, do you mean it automatically unbinds when activity goes background..